# Compare results of two queries on the same SQL table

Tags: mysql

I have 9 rows

```
Timestamp Image Count

t1 Master 10

t1 Slave1 4

t1 Slave2 6

t2 Master 9

t2 Slave1 5

t2 Slave2 4

t3 Master 13

t3 Master 8

t3 Master 6
```

Master count must be equal to sum(slaves count); so i want to find out the timestamp for which master count != sum(slaves count) from this table (Answer would be t3 since 13!= 8+6) What will my SQL query look like?

I want the result to be :

```
t1 10 10

t2 10 10

t3 13 14
```

and so i want a query to show timestamps where master sum != slave sum;

t3 13 14

I am struggling to form the query...

```
select t1.timestamp as T,t1.count as C  from mytable t1, mytable t2 where t1.timestamp<>t2.timestamp and t1.image='Master' group by t1.timestamp;
```

But how do i calculate its sum - and then compare it with another query t1.image !='Master'

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that t3 is as follows:

```
t3 Master 13
t3 **Slave1** 8
t3 **Slave2** 6
```

This query gives the table with both counts:

```
select 
    m1.timestamp as T, 
    m1.count as M_C, 
    sum(m2.Count) as S_C
from mytable m1 
join mytable m2 on m1.timestamp=m2.timestamp and m2.image!="Master" 
where m1.image='Master' 
group by m1.timestamp;
```

For records with only those values where M_C!=S_C, you can run the following nested query:

```
select 
    m1.timestamp as T, 
    m1.count as M_C, 
    sum(m2.Count) as S_C
from mytable m1 
join mytable m2 on m1.timestamp=m2.timestamp 
and m2.image!="Master" 
where m1.image='Master' 
group by m1.timestamp
having S_C!=M_C;
```

Comment: Right - but i want to know those timestamps whose master sum IS NOT EQUAL TO the slaves sum

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).